# asp.net mvc - load side navigation once

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my `_Layout.cshtml` I have a partial view that builds dynamic side navigation menu.

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<html>
    <body>
        .. //top pane div here
        @Html.Partial("_sideNavPartialView")
        ..
        <div>
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        ..    
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to load the side navigation once and not reload if I click a menu. I just want to change the view in the `@RenderBody`. Is there a way that I can do this?

Comment: So when you click on links or buttons in your side nav or anywhere on your page, you don't  want those to actually reload the whole page, just alter the content in the  RenderBody?  That means those links would have to be handled client-side.  What I think you're looking for is more of a SPA approach.  I would suggest reading up on that a bit to see if that would be a good fit for your app.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/november/asp-net-single-page-applications-build-modern-responsive-web-apps-with-asp-net